# Do not show one specific widget on one specific page

Tags: themes, sidebar, child-theme

Using a child theme of genesis and am unsure of how to remove a contact us widget in sidebar from the contact us page.

Is there an easy way to do so?

It's part of the theme which has it on the side so when I remove this widget from one page it's removing it from all of the pages.

I'm using News Pro Theme (child of Genesis) and am unsure of where to edit this in the template files. I know I can simply use a plugin to do this but I'd rather figure this out and have less overhead.

Comment: You can do this with code; but it might be easier to use a plugin; like "[Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/)"?

Comment: @josh - I installed widget logic but I'm not sure what sort of logic to put into it? I want this widget to NOT display on contact page but when I put !is_page('contact') or if(!is_page('contact')) it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure the contact page uses a slug of `contact`?  You can also use the page ID.  You should just need `!is_page( 'contact' )`

Comment: @josh - I got it now. Right before you commented that I checked and it's contact_us so !is_page('contact_us') works. 

Thanks so much as this would've answered it had I not noticed that a moment earlier!

Comment: :)  No worries at all.  This can happen (slug name different from page name) if you go back and edit the title of a page... but do not change it's permalink.  The slug will remain the old page title.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: Ahhh... I just saw the "would rather not use a plugin" from your post above.  If you want a programmatic answer; let me know.. and I'll write one.

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize the page had a machine name of `contact_us` and not just simply contact. When I do

```
!is_page('contact_us')
```

it works.